# using xam.Plugin.DownloadManager Xamarin forms

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

i am using xam.plugin.downloadmanager to download files in my app,once file download i wnats to redirect to downloads native page to view which i was download from  server. is there any way ?? plesae help me [image]

[image]

this is my code Anroid main activity class

```
using Android.OS;
using Plugin.DownloadManager;
using Plugin.DownloadManager.Abstractions;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace Expertential.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "Expertential", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            Downloaded();
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        public void Downloaded()
        {
            CrossDownloadManager.Current.PathNameForDownloadedFile = new System.Func<IDownloadFile, string>(file =>
            {
                string fileName = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(file.Url).Path.Split('/').Last();
                return Path.Combine(ApplicationContext.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath, fileName);
            });
        }


    }
}
```

viewmodel in here iam calling download  .netstandard library

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Expertential.Models;
using Expertential.Services;
using Expertential.ViewModels;
using Plugin.DownloadManager;
using Plugin.DownloadManager.Abstractions;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Expertential.ViewModels
{
    class CustomPopupViewModel :BaseViewModel
    {
        private CustomPopupViewModelService customPopupViewModelService;
        private ObservableCollection<Attachments> attachment;
        public ObservableCollection<Attachments> Attachment
        {
            get { return attachment; }
            set
            {
                attachment = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Attachment));
            }
        }
        public CustomPopupViewModel()
        {

        }

        private int _requertAttHeight;
        public int requertAttHeight { get { return _requertAttHeight; }
            set { _requertAttHeight = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(requertAttHeight));
            }
        }



        private Boolean _taskLoader;
        public Boolean taskLoader
        {
            get { return _taskLoader; }
            set
            {
                _taskLoader = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(taskLoader));
            }
        }

        public IDownloadFile File;
        Boolean isDownloading = true;



        #region custom function

        public void GetAttachments(List<Attachments> attachment)
        {

            Attachment = new ObservableCollection<Attachments>();
            if (attachment.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Attachments att in attachment)
                {
                    var title = att.title;
                     string[] titleArray = title.Split('.');

                    if (titleArray.Length > 1)
                    {
                        setIconVisible(titleArray[1],att);
                    }
                    Attachment.Add(att);
                }

                requertAttHeight = 40 * attachment.Count;
            }


        }


        public  void setIconVisible(string content, Attachments att)
        {
            switch (content)
            {
                case "png":
                case "jpg":
                case "jpeg":
                    att.isWord = false;
                    att.isExcel = false;
                    att.isPdf = false;
                    att.isPpt = false;
                    att.isImage = true;
                    break;




                case "ppt":
                case "pptx":
                    att.isWord = false;
                    att.isExcel = false;
                    att.isPdf = false;
                    att.isPpt = true;
                    att.isImage = false;
                    break;




                case "xlsx":
                case "xls":
                    att.isWord = false;
                    att.isExcel = true;
                    att.isPdf = false;
                    att.isPpt = false;
                    att.isImage = false;
                    break;

                case "docx":
                    att.isWord = true;
                    att.isExcel = false;
                    att.isPdf = false;
                    att.isPpt = false;
                    att.isImage = false;
                    break;


            }
        }

        public async Task<string> GetFileFullUrl(string fileName)
        {
            var strValue = "";
            customPopupViewModelService = new CustomPopupViewModelService();
            strValue = await customPopupViewModelService.GetFileFullUrl(fileName);

            return strValue;
        }



        public async void DownloadFile(string FileName)
        {
            Boolean target = false;
            this.taskLoader = true;
            var DownloadManager = CrossDownloadManager.Current;
            var file = DownloadManager.CreateDownloadFile(FileName);
            await Task.Yield();
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                DownloadManager.Start(file, true);

                while (isDownloading)
                {
                    Task.Delay(100);
                    isDownloading = IsDownloading(file);
                }
            });

            if (!isDownloading)
            {
                this.taskLoader = false;
                target = await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "File Download Goto Download page to view", "Ok", "Cancel");
            }
            if (target)
            {
                // Device.OpenUri(new Uri("Downloads"));
                try
                {
                    await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
                    // here  i want to redirect to downloads app ->
                   // Intent myIntent = new Intent(Android.App.DownloadManager.ActionDownloadComplete);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //// TODO: handle exception
                    //String data = e.getMessage();
                }
                //   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.)
                //var x = file.DestinationPathName;
                //Device.OpenUri(new Uri(x));
            }
        }


        public Boolean IsDownloading(IDownloadFile file)
        {
            if (file == null) return false;

            switch (file.Status)
            {
                case DownloadFileStatus.INITIALIZED:
                case DownloadFileStatus.PAUSED:
                case DownloadFileStatus.PENDING:
                case DownloadFileStatus.RUNNING:
                    return true;

                case DownloadFileStatus.COMPLETED:
                case DownloadFileStatus.CANCELED:
                case DownloadFileStatus.FAILED:
                    return false;

                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        public void AbortDownloading()
        {
            CrossDownloadManager.Current.Abort(File);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't add code as image. ([see here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2249175))

Comment: okay @ Paul Kertscher, i will follow

Comment: Is this really Xamarin.Forms, or rather Xamarin.Android? Looks like the latter to me. the visual-studio, xamarin.ios and xamarin.forms seem inappropriate to me. Could you please edit your post accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of your question tells me you want to open the default downloads application that Android has and it can be done as follows:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(DownloadManager.ActionViewDownloads);
 intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
 Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Yes this is what i expected, i accomplished  with some changes in your code  Intent intent = new Intent(DownloadManager.ActionViewDownloads);
                    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                    Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);

Comment: I have updated my answer kindly take a look and mark it as correct!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is what i expected, i accomplished  with some changes in your code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(DownloadManager.ActionViewDownloads);
 intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
 Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```